# How do you open a TextMate tab in an another window?

Tags: textmate

I have two monitors on my system and sometimes I want to open a tab (i.e. file) from one window in its own window.

Is this possible?

Comment: You have two questions here and really should break them apart.

Comment: I edited the question and removed your "piggy back" question, "btw, when doing a find, how do I do a find next using a shortcut?" and asked a new question for it, since I am interested in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't move a *tab* to a new window (yet? see [this suggestion](http://wiki.macromates.com/Suggestions/OpenInNewWindow)), but you *can* open a file in a new window from the drawer. Right-click the file in the drawer and choose "Open *filename* in New Window."

Find next is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Find Next is `Cmd-g`.  Moving a tab is View > Move to New Window.  Exploring the menus would be a good idea.</strike>
Ignore me, confused editors (see comments).

Comment: mine doesn't have View > Move to new window (version 1.5.1)

Comment: *sigh* I always confuse TextWrangler and TextMate for some reason.  Ignore me.

Comment: Cmd G is right though. For find next. Kinda standard on a Mac (web browsers, etc).