# In TextMate what is the keyboard shortcut for Find Next?

Tags: textmate

When doing a Find in TextMate, what is the shortcut for Find Next?

This question was spun-off of [How do you open a TextMate tab in an another Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201263/how-do-you-open-a-textmate-tab-in-a-another-window), where it was a piggy-back question on the main question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

All you have to do is click `Edit` > `Find` > `Find Next` and look at the shortcut next to it.